# Do all girls at Duel Academy get assigned to the Obelisk Blue dormitory, regardless of skill?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, yu-gi-oh-gx

I noticed while watching the early *Yu-Gi-Oh! GX* episodes that the only girls we see at the Duel Academy are part of Obelisk Blue, a dormitory said to be reserved for the most skilled duelists (and with the most luxurious accommodations). In Episode 2, we see each dorm hosting a welcome feast, but the only girls present are in Obelisk Blue (and separate from the boys):

[image: Obelisk Blue boys welcome dinner]
[image: Obelisk Blue girls welcome dinner]
[image: Ra Yellow welcome dinner]
[image: Slifer Red welcome dinner]

Do all girls at Duel Academy get assigned to the Obelisk Blue dormitory, regardless of skill? Seems a bit unfair to the boys if they do...

Comment: http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Ra_Yellow

Comment: http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Slifer_Red?file=Slifer_red_girls.jpg

Comment: @Valorum The red uniform looks like it's from the non-canon online game (where a player can dress their avatar in it). The yellow looks more debatable to me since it could just be academy staff.

Comment: Hence why I didn't post these pics as answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes. It's said that the Obelisk Blue is the richest and biggest dorm, so it's the only one that has the space and means to keep the girls. So yes, any girl on the Duel Academy is in Obelisk Blue... in a separate building.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have some solid evidence (e.g. quotes from an episode) to support this claim?

Answer (score 0):

my theory is that dueling (at least at that time) was a male-dominated thing so most of the students are male while the few girls are all skilled enough to be in the best dorm because they worked harder to get there and that's their payoff.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F! This seems like a personal theory.  Do you have some solid evidence (e.g. quotes from an episode) to support this claim?

Answer (score 0):

That's what the wiki says, yet we have [Blair Flannigan](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Blair_Flannigan) (Rei Saotome) in [Slifer](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Slifer_Red) during season 3. Though to my knowledge, she's the only exception.

> Blair Flannigan, known as Rei Saotome (早乙女さおとめ レイ Saotome Rei) in the Japanese version, is an underage student and the only girl in the Slifer Red dorm. Initially a minor character appearing in a stand-alone episode during the first season, Blair joins the central cast at the beginning of the third after proving her worth as a Duelist.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).